# How to access the timestamp value from Overpass meta requests with Openlayers.Format.OSM?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, update, format

I am using Overpass-api to request data, then display it in an interactive webpage using Openlayers. When user clicks on some feature, the information is shown in popup.

As of now, the page is working nicely and displays all the tags.

I want to add the **"last updated time"** of the feature in the popup, which will correspond to the **"timestamp"** value in the **"Overpass-api meta request"** but i cannot access that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this answer for same question on osm help https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20499/how-to-access-the-timestamp-value-from-overpass-meta-requests-with-openlayersformatosm